# Why does this pattern for combining two lists require triple underscores (___) to work?

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

I understand that `__` is a list of one or more elements, and that `___` is 0 or more elements, but when I try this rule with 2 underscores I don't get the results I expect.

```
cartesianProduct[lis1_, lis2_] := 
 ReplaceList[{lis1, lis2}, {{___, x_, ___}, {___, y_, ___}} :> {x, y}]

cartesianProduct[{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}]

(* {{a, x}, {a, y}, {a, z}, {b, x}, {b, y}, {b, z}, {c, x}, {c, y}, {c, z}} *)
```

I guess I do not understand the difference between `_`, `__`, and `___`. Which is the pattern for instructing *Mathematica* to do what I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's first look at what a pattern with two underscores, i.e. `{__, x_, __}` does. You're asking *Mathematica* to match an expression that has the structure (pseudocode)

```
{<one or more elements I don't care about>, <call this x>, <one or more elements I don't care about>}
```

So when you try to match a 3 element list with the above pattern, the only element that will match `x` is the middle element. `x` is constrained, because the part that you don't care about, i.e. `__` is at least 1 element long on each end. Hence, when you use only `__` in your code, you get only `{b, y}` (i.e., the middle elements in each list) as your output.

What you instead want, is for `x` to match *every* possible element in the list. For that, you need to account (somehow) for the fact that if `x` is the first element in the list, there are no elements (or zero) *before* it. In order to do this, you need `___` before and after `x`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!  Makes almost perfect sense, I think I have been working for too long.  Will reread this tomorrow morning.